# How to handle parameters that can be an ARRAY or OBJECT in Retrofit on Android?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm having an issue where the API I'm parsing returns an OBJECT for an ARRAY of size 1.

For example, sometimes the API will respond with:

```
{
    "monument": [
        {
            "key": 4152,
            "name": "MTS - Corporate Head Office",
            "categories": {},
            "address": {}
        },
        {
            "key": 4151,
            "name": "Canadian Transportation Agency",
            "categories": {},
            "address": {}
        },
        {
            "key": 4153,
            "name": "Bank of Montreal Building",
            "categories": {},
            "address": {}
        }
    ],
}
```

However, if the `monument` array has only 1 item it becomes an OBJECT (note the lack of `[]` brackets) like so:

```
{
    "monument": {
        "key": 4152,
        "name": "MTS - Corporate Head Office",
        "categories": {},
        "address": {}
    }
}
```

If I define my models like this, I will get an error when only a single item is returned:

```
public class Locations {
    public List<Monument> monument;
}
```

If only a single item is returned I get the following error:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY ...
```

And if I define my model like so:

```
public class Locations {
    public Monument monument;
}
```

and the API returns an ARRAY I get the opposite error

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY  but was BEGIN_OBJECT ...
```

I cannot define multiple items with the same name in my model.
How can I handle this case?

Note: I cannot make changes to the API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a complement to my previous answer, here's a solution using a `TypeAdapter`.

```
public class LocationsTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Locations> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Locations locations) throws IOException {
        gson.toJson(locations, Locations.class, jsonWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public Locations read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        Locations locations;

        jsonReader.beginObject();
        jsonReader.nextName();       

        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            locations = new Locations((Monument[]) gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Monument[].class));
        } else if(jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            locations = new Locations((Monument) gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Monument.class));
        } else {
            throw new JsonParseException("Unexpected token " + jsonReader.peek());
        }

        jsonReader.endObject();
        return locations;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help pakerfeldt!

Comment: How to use it? @pakerfeldt

Comment: Same question. How to use this class?

Comment: See the other answer for implementation.

Answer (score 14):

The trick is to ***write your own Gson deserializer*** for your `Locations` class. This would check whether the monument element is an object or an array. Like so:

```
public class LocationsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Locations> {

    @Override
    public Locations deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonElement monumentElement = json.getAsJsonObject().get("monument");
        if (monumentElement.isJsonArray()) {
            return new Locations((Monument[]) context.deserialize(monumentElement.getAsJsonArray(), Monument[].class));
        } else if (monumentElement.isJsonObject()) {
            return new Locations((Monument) context.deserialize(monumentElement.getAsJsonObject(), Monument.class));
        } else {
            throw new JsonParseException("Unsupported type of monument element");
        }
    }
}
```

For the convenience, add a vararg constructor to your `Locations` class:

```
public class Locations {
    public List<Monument> monuments;

    public Locations(Monument ... ms) {
        monuments = Arrays.asList(ms);
    }
}
```

Your Monument class stays the same. Something like:

```
public class Monument {
    public int key;
    public String name;
    // public Categories categories;
    // public Address address;
}
```

Finally, create your own `Gson` object and pass it to the retrofit `RestAdapter`.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Locations.class, new LocationsDeserializer()).create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(baseUrl)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks pakerfeldt. How would you do this using a TypeAdapter (which is recommended over JsonDeserializer by the GSON authors)?

Comment: `New applications should prefer TypeAdapter, whose streaming API is more efficient than this interface's tree API.` Ref: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html

Comment: Haven't done that, but JavaDoc should help you: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html
Like siva said, do `peek()` on the `JsonReader` to check if it's an object or an array.

Comment: The JsonReader has a pretty good example: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html

Looks like you have to consume/deserialize the whole object using the `TypeAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for the starting points w/ `TypeAdapter`. Do you know if it's possible to call a default GSON `TypeAdapter` from within the custom one that I create? The JSON response has many nested objects and I'm trying to avoid manually deserializing all of them for each custom `TypeAdapter` I create. Also to avoid duplication of code.

Comment: Here's a gist of what I'm working on: https://gist.github.com/ryanram/2b3b6b0aea16d2a82096/

Comment: If you're happy with any of the answers you might wanna go ahead and marked one of them as an answer.

Comment: Perfect work for retrofit2 error-expected begin_array but was begin_object ,When list have only one item

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `TypeAdapter` with Gson which conditionally handles this behavior.

You'd call `peekToken()` first. If it was `BEGIN_ARRAY` then just deserialize as `List<Foo>`. If it's `BEGIN_OBJECT` then deserialize as `Foo` and wrap in `Collections.singletonList`.

Now you always have a list whether it's a single item or many.