# Do I have to handle every data type in a custom Deserailizer?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I've created a TypeAdapter as prescribed by pakerfeldt here [How to handle parameters that can be an ARRAY or OBJECT in Retrofit on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500772/how-to-handle-parameters-that-can-be-an-array-or-object-in-retrofit-on-android).

But I am getting this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 69 path $.response

I'm thinking it's because my Type Adapter doesn't handle each data type in my POJO which includes Strings and Foo[]. First, does my TypeAdapter have to handle all the data types in the POJO? My follow up question is am I wasting my time with a custom deserializer because this is something RxJava handles automatically in a case where the Observable will give my subscriber the correct POJO?

Thanks