# How to use gson TypeAdapter in Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have a working code wherein my retrofit client can retrieve a List of objects(country) from an api. The problem is, the parameter used by the api returns an ARRAY if I used to retrieve all the countries then it returns a single OBJECT when I want to query for a single country. As a result the following exception is shown.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 4 column 17 path $.RestResponse.result
```

By the way, I'm using Retrofit 2.

I tried the accepted answer in this thread
[How to handle parameters that can be an ARRAY or OBJECT in Retrofit on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500772/how-to-handle-parameters-that-can-be-an-array-or-object-in-retrofit-on-android)

But still it won't work. Here is my implementation.

API

```
http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/{alpha2_code}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("country/get/all")
    Call<Example> getCountry();

    @GET("country/get/iso2code/{alpha2_code}")
    Call<Example> searchCountryByIso2Code(@Path("alpha2_code") String alpha2Code);

    @GET("country/get/iso3code/{alpha3_code}")
    Call<Example> searchCountryByIso3Code(@Path("alpha3_code") String alpha3Code);

    @GET("country/search?text={text to search}")
    Call<Example> searchCountry(@Path("text to search") String searchText);
}
```

CountryTypeAdapter

```
public class CountryTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<RestResponse> {

    private Gson mGson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, RestResponse restResponse) throws IOException {
        mGson.toJson(restResponse, RestResponse.class, jsonWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public RestResponse read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        RestResponse result;

        jsonReader.beginObject();
        jsonReader.nextName();

        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            result = new RestResponse((Result[]) mGson.fromJson(jsonReader, Result.class));
        } else if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            result = new RestResponse((Result) mGson.fromJson(jsonReader, Result.class));
        } else {
            throw new JsonParseException("Unexpected token " + jsonReader.peek());
        }

        jsonReader.endObject();
        return result;
    }
}
```

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://services.groupkt.com/";
    private static Retrofit mRetrofit;

    public static Retrofit getmRetrofitClient(){

        if (mRetrofit == null) {
            mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(CountryTypeAdapter.class, new CountryTypeAdapter()).create()))
                    .build();
        }
        return mRetrofit;
    }

}
```

EDIT:
RestResponse

```
public class RestResponse {

    @SerializedName("messages")
    @Expose
    private List<String> messages = null;
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result = null;

    public RestResponse() {
    }

    public RestResponse(List<String> messages, List<Result> result) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public RestResponse(Result... result) {
        this.result = Arrays.asList(result);
    }

    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }


}
```

Comment: try  Call<List<Example>> getCountry(); and remove Gson Tyadapter from APICLIENT

Comment: the exception is still shown..

Comment: You can't use "Example" for all your requests if the API response is different. One will be a something like "<List<Example>>" and the other just a single "Example" object.

Comment: I have added the RestResponse class. From the other thread I made a constructor that accepts varargs so that I can convert it into a list and even though it contains only a single object..

Comment: You can't reuse - private List<Result> result = null - for both responses. The API returns an array when you get all and a single "Result" when you get one result. Try duplicating your RestResponse and replace it with private Result result

Answer (score 6):

There are some issues in your code, and some of them can be either fixed or redesigned in order to simplify a lot of things. First, let's take a look at the service (the names differ). Retrofit interface must use `@Query` for requests with query parameters, not `@Path`. Also, your service methods must return a `Call` where its `T` declare the actual result type giving some information on what's returned by that method. The service you mentioned can return a single element or none (but never HTTP 404 for some reason), or a list depending on endpoint URLs. Let's assume, single values and none values are not meant to be 1- or 0-sized lists:

```java
interface IService {

    @GET("country/get/all")
    Call<List<Country>> getCountries();

    @GET("country/get/iso2code/{code}")
    Call<Country> getCountryByIso2Code(
            @Path("code") String code
    );

    @GET("country/get/iso3code/{code}")
    Call<Country> getCountryByIso3Code(
            @Path("code") String code
    );

    @GET("country/search")
    Call<List<Country>> searchCountries(
            @Query("text") String query
    );

}
```

Next, the `Country` class may look as follows:

```java
final class Country {

    @SerializedName("name")
    final String name = null;

    @SerializedName("alpha2_code")
    final String code2 = null;

    @SerializedName("alpha3_code")
    final String code3 = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + '(' + code2 + ',' + code3 + ')';
    }

}
```

Note that `@SerializedName` can map an external name to a local field name, and the fields are `final` and `null`ified - Gson can deal with them itself. Next, I'm assuming that you don't really care the response structure, and only need `$.Response.result` that should be adapted respectively. `TypeAdapterFactory` is what you need and can work with any response, not necessarily for countries:

```java
final class ResponseExtractorTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final Gson gson;

    private ResponseExtractorTypeAdapterFactory(final Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getResponseExtractorTypeAdapterFactory(final Gson gson) {
        return new ResponseExtractorTypeAdapterFactory(gson);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson responseGson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Using responseGson would result in infinite recursion since this type adapter factory overrides any type
        return new ResponseExtractorTypeAdapter<>(gson, typeToken.getType());
    }

    private static final class ResponseExtractorTypeAdapter<T>
            extends TypeAdapter<T> {

        private final Gson gson;
        private final Type type;

        private ResponseExtractorTypeAdapter(final Gson gson, final Type type) {
            this.gson = gson;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            T result = null;
            // Strip the top most enclosing { for $
            in.beginObject();
            final String name1 = in.nextName();
            switch ( name1 ) {
            case "RestResponse":
                // RestResponse { for $.Response
                in.beginObject();
                while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                    final String name2 = in.nextName();
                    switch ( name2 ) {
                    case "messages":
                        // If it's just $.Response.message, then skip it
                        in.skipValue();
                        break;
                    case "result":
                        // If it's $.Response.result, then delegate it to "real" Gson
                        result = gson.fromJson(in, type);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new MalformedJsonException("Unexpected at $.RestResponse: " + name2);
                    }
                }
                // RestResponse } for $.Response
                in.endObject();
                break;
            default:
                throw new MalformedJsonException("Unexpected at $: " + name1);
            }
            // Strip the top most enclosing } for $
            in.endObject();
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

Putting it all together:

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            // configure whatever you like
            .create();
    final Gson responseGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getResponseExtractorTypeAdapterFactory(gson))
            .create();
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://services.groupkt.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(responseGson))
            .build();
    final IService apiInterface = retrofit.create(IService.class);
    apiInterface.getCountries().enqueue(callback("getCountries()")); // http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
    apiInterface.getCountryByIso2Code("UA").enqueue(callback("getCountryByIso2Code()")); // http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/UA
    apiInterface.getCountryByIso3Code("UKR").enqueue(callback("getCountryByIso3Code()")); // http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso3code/UKR
    apiInterface.searchCountries("land").enqueue(callback("searchCountries()")); // http://services.groupkt.com/country/search?text=land
}

private static <T> Callback<T> callback(final String name) {
    return new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Call<T> call, final Response<T> response) {
            // Just make sure the output is not written in middle
            synchronized ( System.out ) {
                System.out.print(name);
                System.out.print(": ");
                System.out.println(response.body());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Call<T> call, final Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    };
}
```

And the result (assuming the responses are received and processed sequentally + the long responses are cut):

> getCountries(): [Afghanistan(AF,AFG), Åland Islands(AX,ALA), Albania(AL,ALB), ..., Yemen(YE,YEM), Zambia(ZM,ZMB), Zimbabwe(ZW,ZWE)]
>
> getCountryByIso2Code(): Ukraine(UA,UKR)
>
> getCountryByIso3Code(): Ukraine(UA,UKR)
>
> searchCountries(): [Åland Islands(AX,ALA), Bouvet Island(BV,BVT), Cayman Islands(KY,CYM), ..., United States Minor Outlying Islands(UM,UMI), Virgin Islands (British)(VG,VGB), Virgin Islands (U.S.)(VI,VIR)]