# Parse NoSQL Response with Gson

Tags: android, json, nosql, gson

Im trying to parse a JSON object returned from a mongoDB instance and I'm running into an issue when parsing out document IDs. See the example response below:

```
{  
    "type_id":"zyxwv54321",
    "content":{  
       "contentsA":{  
          "abcd123":{  },
          "efgh123":{  },
          "ijkl123":{  },
          "mnop123":{  },
          "qrst123":{  },
          "uvwx123":{  },
          "yzab123":{  }
       },
       "contentsB":{  
          "abcd123":{  },
          "efgh123":{  },
          "ijkl123":{  },
          "mnop123":{  },
          "qrst123":{  },
          "uvwx123":{  },
          "yzab123":{  }
       }
    },
    "manager":"mail@mail.com"
}
```

The issue is with the objects within `contentsA` and `contentsB`, how do I go about parsing those out? Each of the strings contained in those objects is a unique ID that will change, so a data model class is hard to come by given the unknown nature of those keys.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement your own custom serializer/deserializer that can parse JSON with dynamic key values. It's not going to be pretty, but it's not terrible. And actually provides several advantages in terms of performance:

1. Your JSON is not parsed all at once and instead parsed in a streaming manner
2. You can do interesting things with that, as you can wrap that data with some reactive programming and some persistent storage, and start immediately display something to the user as you are parsing JSON (because users hate waiting...)

Using GSON (but really any library will be similar in concept) you would need to describe your object in your parsing algorithm + [implement a custom TypeAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642933/how-to-use-gson-typeadapter-in-retrofit-2) so that your network call can return a populated Data Model class. So something like this:

```
val jsonReader = JsonReader(inputStream.reader())
jsonReader.isLenient = true //I recommend reading up on this flag
jsonReader.beginObject()
parseInternals(jsonReader)
jsonReader.endObject()
```

Now in your `parseInternal` function you'd need to go through the fields as the response is being streamed and check for JsonToken type (it's an enum)

```
fun parseInternals(jsonReader: JsonReader): YourDataModel {
 //check there are still tokens to parse in your JSON
 val yourDataModel = YourDataModel()
 while (jsonReader.hasNext()) { 
   //name is a key in your JSON
   if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NAME) { 
     val fieldName = jsonReader.readName()
     if (fieldName == "type_id") {
       dataModel.typeId = jsonReader.nextString()

     }
     //and so on until you populate your data model class
   }
 }
}
```

Your next token would be **content** which starts as another object, so you would need to manually do `jsonReader.begin/endObject()` until you get to those dynamic keys, which are just `nextName` in your parser. Make sure to keep checking the type of the next token with `jsonReader.peek()` and comparing that with what you'd expect to be there.

After writing your parser, write some unit tests for it to make sure it's doing what you'd expect it to do. This will help with future proofing in case the JSON schema ever changes so you could catch it early.