# ARRAY or OBJECT in Retrofit on Android using TypeAdapter, in a two depth level

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm struggling with TypeAdapter. Indeed for a json field, I can have an Array (when it's empty) or an Object (when it's not empty). This can't be changed.

Here is the JSON received :

```
{
    "notifications": [
        {
            ...
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "total": 13,
            "count": 13,
            "per_page": 20,
            "current_page": 1,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "links": []
        }
    }
}
```

The field concerned is `links`, as you can see the field is inside `pagination`, which is inside `meta`. And that's my issue, I don't know how the TypeAdapter has to handle `links` in a two depth level.

I used this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500772/how-to-handle-parameters-that-can-be-an-array-or-object-in-retrofit-on-android) to start building a solution. Here it is :

My Custom TypeAdapter class :

```
public class PaginationTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Pagination> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Pagination pagination) throws IOException {
        gson.toJson(pagination, Links.class, out);
    }

    @Override
    public Pagination read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {

        Pagination pagination;

        jsonReader.beginObject();

        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            pagination = new Pagination((Links[]) gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Links[].class));
        } else if(jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            pagination = new Pagination((Links) gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Links.class));
        } else {
            throw new JsonParseException("Unexpected token " + jsonReader.peek());
        }

        return pagination;
    }
}
```

My Pagination class :

```
public class Pagination {

    private int total;

    private int count;

    @SerializedName("per_page")
    private int perPage;

    @SerializedName("current_page")
    private int currentPage;

    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    private int totalPages;

    private Links links;


    Pagination(Links ... links) {
        List<Links> linksList = Arrays.asList(links);
        this.links = linksList.get(0);
    }
}
```

And I'm building my Gson object like that :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Pagination.class, new PaginationTypeAdapter()).create();
```

For now my error is : `com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Unexpected token NAME`

So I know I'm not doing it right, because I'm building my Gson with pagination. But I don't know how it should be handle. Using a TypeAdapter with `meta` ?

Any help will be welcome, thanks !

Comment: Checkout here to know about how to handle [Nested Objects in Gson TypeAdapter](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement a custom type adapter, make sure that your type adapter has balanced token reading and writing: if you open a composite token pair like `[` and `]`, you have to close it (applies for both `JsonWriter` and `JsonReader`). You just don't need this line to fix your issue:

```java
jsonReader.beginObject();
```

because it moves the `JsonReader` instance to the next token, so the next token after `BEGIN_OBJECT` is either `NAME` or `END_OBJECT` (the former in your case sure).

---

#### Alternative option #1

I would suggest also not to use ad-hoc `Gson` object instatiation -- this won't share the configuration between `Gson` instances (say, your "global" `Gson` has a lot of custom adapters registered, but this internal does not have any thus your (de)serialization results might be very unexpected). In order to overcome this, just use `TypeAdapterFactory` that is more context-aware than a "free" `Gson` instance.

```java
final class PaginationTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory paginationTypeAdapterFactory = new PaginationTypeAdapterFactory();

    private PaginationTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getPaginationTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return paginationTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Classes can be compared using == and !=
        if ( typeToken.getRawType() != Pagination.class ) {
            // Not Pagination? Let Gson pick up the next best-match
            return null;
        }
        // Here we get the references for two types adapters:
        // - this is what Gson.fromJson does under the hood
        // - we save some time for the further (de)serialization
        // - you classes should not ask more than they require
        final TypeAdapter<Links> linksTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(Links.class);
        final TypeAdapter<Links[]> linksArrayTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(Links[].class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new PaginationTypeAdapter(linksTypeAdapter, linksArrayTypeAdapter);
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    private static final class PaginationTypeAdapter
            extends TypeAdapter<Pagination> {

        private final TypeAdapter<Links> linksTypeAdapter;
        private final TypeAdapter<Links[]> linksArrayTypeAdapter;

        private PaginationTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<Links> linksTypeAdapter, final TypeAdapter<Links[]> linksArrayTypeAdapter) {
            this.linksTypeAdapter = linksTypeAdapter;
            this.linksArrayTypeAdapter = linksArrayTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Pagination pagination)
                throws IOException {
            linksTypeAdapter.write(out, pagination.links);
        }

        @Override
        public Pagination read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            final JsonToken token = in.peek();
            // Switches are somewhat better: you can let your IDE or static analyzer to check if you covered ALL the cases
            switch ( token ) {
            case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                return new Pagination(linksArrayTypeAdapter.read(in));
            case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                return new Pagination(linksTypeAdapter.read(in));
            case END_ARRAY:
            case END_OBJECT:
            case NAME:
            case STRING:
            case NUMBER:
            case BOOLEAN:
            case NULL:
            case END_DOCUMENT:
                // MalformedJsonException, not sure, might be better, because it's an IOException and the read method throws IOException
                throw new MalformedJsonException("Unexpected token: " + token + " at " + in);
            default:
                // Maybe some day Gson adds something more here... Let be prepared
                throw new AssertionError(token);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

#### Alternative option #2

You can annotate your `private Links links;` with `@JsonAdapter` and bind a type adapter factory *directly* to links: `Gson` will "inject" `links` objects directly to `Pagination` instances, so you don't even need a constructor there.

Comment: Awesome !! Just by removing one line of code it work. I should have been more aware of how TypeAdapter. Thanks very much for your help.

I will check your alternative option too :)