# Retrofit complex object webservice response

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I started using Retrofit in my android app consuming RESTful web services.

It works quite well, but I'm facing an issue.

The webservice answer always look like this :

```
{"code":"ok","message":"","response":
```

Response can either be a String (`"response":""`), a json element (`"response":{}`), or a json array (`"response":[{}{}]`)

I started creating classes for everything like CustemerResponse

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
}


public class CustomerResponse extends Response {
    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    private JsonArray response;
}
```

But this seems quite an overkill, as I will have to create multiple classes for every responses I'm likely to get.

Is there an easyer way to say I will always get a response of either String, JsonElement, JsonArray, and cast this response to the corect type like Customer or `List<Customer>`.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean, you no need to create a new model class for ever response.

Comment: but If ther was a way to say that I only want the response field, I could do 
    `@POST("/remote/json.php?customer_get")Call<Customer>`     `getCustomer(@Body CustomerRequest customerRequest);` Instead which would be much more simple

Comment: why do you use post for a get request?

Comment: Checkout this post it could be help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500772/how-to-handle-parameters-that-can-be-an-array-or-object-in-retrofit-on-android

Comment: I have to post the parameters like sessionId, and customerId, to get the right customer.