# How to handle unknown response type with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit and GSON
before retrofit, I have created a custom class for API calls, and map data manually.

This is my standard Response Type

```
{
  "timestamp",
  "status",
  "message",
  "payLoad",
  "error"
}
```

If I GET the error from the server so my response is like

```
{
  "timestamp":123456789,
  "status":302,
  "message":"Send All Data",
  "error":"Partial Content"
}
```

If I get Success but Payload IS JSONObject so response like

```
{
  "timestamp":123456789,
  "status":200,
  "message":"Save Successfully",
  "payLoad":"{
    "token": "...",
    "userDetails": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "...",
      "firstName": "Deepak",
      "lastName": "Gupta",
      "gender": "MALE",
      "address": ...,
      "demoModel": {
        "id": 1,
        "demo": "enginner",
        "demoConstant": "ENGINNER",
        "active": true
      },
      "registrationDate": 1585831235533,
      "enabled": true,
    "expireTime": 4178010611915}
}
```

If I get Success but Payload IS JSONArray so response like

```
{
    "timestamp": 1586330473808,
    "status": 200,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "payLoad": [
        {
            ...
        },{
            ...
        },{
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to make Payload to Object and then using InstanceOf I'll cast to respective model or List but then getting error linkedtreemap not cast to list or Object.

Comment: You can not hold array or object in same property with GSON .. Just make the `payLoad` and array for each case or do the parsing your self ..

Comment: @ADM is there any way that I pass the single POJO Model For Response and After that, I'll check its JSONArray Or JSONObject...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500772/how-to-handle-parameters-that-can-be-an-array-or-object-in-retrofit-on-android ..

Comment: @ADM I tried the given solution but not worked ...